# How to make a rounded button in FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm developing Delphi Firemonkey mobile application. I want to make a rounded button in Firemonkey. How can i do this without using 3rd party components?

Answer (score 9):

Use TCornerButton.

This represents a button with customizable corners.

Use the Corners property to choose the corners to be customized and the CornerType, XRadius, and YRadius properties to customize the corners.

Comment: This is not working in android, Its woking only on windows. Any idea how to curve the corners for android fmx

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of ways to do rounded buttons in FMX. You can use some different components for making buttons like `TRectangle`.

Personally I use and suggest you to use `TRectangle` too.

- Put a `TRectangle` to your FMX Form.
- Set your **Rectangle1**'s `Height` and `Width` values to `70` *(for e.g.)*
- Change `XRadius` and `YRadius` values to `35` *(it depends on height-width values)*

> If you want to make more satisfying button, you should change `Fill`
>   and `Stroke` properties.

*for e.g.*

- Set `Fill.Color` is `#FF0288D1` *(to use Hax color code, add 2 FF to first digit)*
- Set `Fill.Kind` is `Solid`

If you don't want to use `Stroke` (Border for Button) Set `Stroke.Kind` to `None`.

> Also you can add `TLabel` or `TImage` component into your Rectangle1
>   component and be sure that you set `Align` property well.